# update only on first count

Tags: sql, sql-server

The counter only when the count is 1 and not on subsequent additions

```
if exists (select 1 from login_counter where emailaddress = @useremail)
    update login_counter 
    set counts = counts+1, - here i want to add a check if the count is 1, add the lasttry which is justbelow to the date but every new count, don't update that 
        lasttry = GETDATE() 
    where emailaddress = @useremail;
else
    insert into login_counter (counts, emailaddress, lasttry) 
    values (1, @useremail, GETDATE());
```

I tried like this:

the counter only when the count is 1 and not on subsequent additions

```
if exists (select 1 from login_counter where emailaddress = @useremail)
    update login_counter 
    set counts = counts + 1,
        lasttry = CASE WHEN (select lasttry from login_counter where emailaddress = @useremail) = NULL THEN GetDate() 
    where emailaddress = @useremail;
else
    insert into login_counter (counts,emailaddress,lasttry) 
    values (1, @useremail, GETDATE());
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Comment: in the `CASE` statement, use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`.  Also you'll probably need to add a `TOP 1` to that nested `SELECT` statement

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  But in terms of syntax, `case` *expressions* require an `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do, but you are getting the syntax error because this line:

```
lasttry = CASE WHEN (select lasttry from login_counter where emailaddress = @useremail) = NULL THEN GetDate()
```

is missing an `END` for the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably rewrite your case statement like this:

```
lasttry = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (select lasttry from login_counter where emailaddress = @useremail) THEN GetDate() END
```

Otherwise, you would want to make sure your subquery inside the `CASE` returns only a single value, for example `SELECT TOP 1 lasttry ...` or `SELECT MAX(lasttry) ...`. If the subquery return multiple values, your comparison expression will bomb.